# WPF DataGrid: Add items?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to add items to my `DataGrid`. The count of the `DataGrid` is correct. If I put 3 items in the `DataGrid`, 3 rows are shown when I run the program, but no data is shown. All fields are just blank. I'm using this code:

```
public void LoadTimeRegistrationData()
{
    _timeregistrations = _client.TimeRegistrations().GetTimeregistrations("10-080002");

    gridDataTimeRegistrations.Items.Add("Test");
    gridDataTimeRegistrations.Items.Add("Test1");
    gridDataTimeRegistrations.Items.Add("Test2");
}
```

And the Xaml:

```
<Custom:DataGrid x:Name="gridDataTimeRegistrations" MinWidth="600" MinHeight="100"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee no." Width="110"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" Width="175"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="100"/>
        <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="50"/>
    </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
</Custom:DataGrid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the XAML of your DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to set up bindings for [text columns](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/19/wpf-datagrid-stock-and-template-columns.aspx).